# How to remove the pagination limit in prestashop 1.6

Tags: pagination, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I want to remove the pagination   limit or set something called show all or show all records 
since  when i click the export button it limits my records so , i want to show all the records that are available ,So that in one click i can export all the records. how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The limit options in the dropdown are set in classes/controller/AdminController.php:

```
/** @var array Number of results in list per page (used in select field) */
protected $_pagination = array(20, 50, 100, 300, 1000);`
```

The default pagination limit (on first load) is defined directly below:

```
/** @var int Default number of results in list per page */
protected $_default_pagination = 50;
```

You can change this variable by overriding AdminController, you can read more about overriding files in PrestaShop here:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors#Overridingdefaultbehaviors-Overridingaclass

Comment: thats working  but when  I click the Export button I don't want to limit my record

Comment: @JerryAbraham, did you try it and find out Export is still limited?

Comment: @JerryAbraham weird, as you can see in AdminController@processExport there's not limit at all, it's just go line after line from a list view where a limit is defined in $_pagination

Comment: **NEVER** change values directly in core files! Extend the controller itself, or one of its children, and then change the value. The value is `protected` which means that children classes will have access to it.

Comment: @JulienLachal is right, my bad, i missread protected with private :)